# Autofocus on input field when div slides down

Tags: jquery, css, input, autofocus

I have is a hidden div. When the button is clicked, the div slides down with an input field. How do I make this input field autofocus as soon as the div slides down? Thanks.

```
<input type="text" name="comment_field" id="comment_field" placeholder="Comment..." />
```

is what I have and is in a div

```
$("#status_comments_"+a).slideDown();
    $("#comment_field").focus();
```

I tried to use the above, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `slideDown`'s callback function which is executed when animation is complete.

```
$("#status_comments_"+a).slideDown(function(){
    $("#comment_field").focus();
});
```

Note that IDs must be unique, otherwise your ID selector only selects the first element with that specific ID. If input element is within the div tag you can also code:

```
$("#status_comments_"+a).slideDown(function(){
    $('input', this).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#divID").focus();
```

or without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('divID').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#divId").show().focus();

document.getElementById('divID').focus();
```

Answer (score -1):

hidden field cannot gain focus ..so what you need to do is on  click of button you have to show them .

```
$("#status_comments_"+a).show().slideDown();
    $("#comment_field").show().focus();
```