# How to set input `autofocus` on when it is toggle?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have is a hidden div. When a link is clicked, the `div` should be toggle with an `input` field and a dropdown `select`. How do I make this input field `autofocus` as soon as the div slides down?

This is my HTML for hidden `DIV`:

```
<div class="new-category-box">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_category" name="new_category" autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="parentCategoryList">
            <option>-- Parent Category --</option>
            <option value="">Lorem ipsum</option>
            <option value="">Lorem ipsdffum</option>
        </select>   
    </div>      
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add New Category</button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I went through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440188/autofocus-on-input-field-when-div-slides-down). But now this `DIV` not toggle.

This is my Jquery:

```
$( "a.add_new_category" ).click(function() {
    $( ".new-category-box" ).slideToggle(function(){
            $("#new_category").focus();
        });
    );
});
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong this code?

Comment: can you share your work on a fiddle

Comment: Try to use the JavaScript from my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors, they have been corrected:

```js
$( "a.add_new_category" ).click(function() {
  $( ".new-category-box" ).slideToggle(function() {
    $("#new_category").focus();
  });
  // ); - extra stuff need to be removed!
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new-category-box">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_category" name="new_category" autofocus>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="parentCategoryList">
      <option>-- Parent Category --</option>
      <option value="">Lorem ipsum</option>
      <option value="">Lorem ipsdffum</option>
    </select>   
  </div>      
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add New Category</button>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" autofocus>
```

Comment: His question is precisely that condition: he wants the field to autofocus, but *only* when its parent div becomes visible with a toggle. So the `autofocus` doesn't help, because even when the div is hidden, the form behind the scenes is triggering autofocus, which causes weird behavior in phones etc (keyboard pops up, but there's no place to enter).